# iPhone app doesn't show up after installing from cydia?

Tags: ios, xcode, cydia

I recently finished my project in xcode and decided to test it on my iPhone 4 via Cydia. I took the .app file from xcode, uploaded it to myrepospace.com/ideb, made it a deb file and then finally I uploaded it to my account on myrepospace.com. After installing it from Cydia, it doesn't show up on the home-screen. Why? I tried restarting the phone but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you install openSSH ( from cydia ) and directly upload your application and then reboot. This should work fine.

Also make sure you compile an arm application and not an intel version which is used in the simulator.